# Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured

Tags: flutter

I tried to update flutter from this command using cmd:

```
flutter upgrade
```

And I got:

```
Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter' in C:\flutter
```

What is the reason and how I can solve this?

Comment: on MacOS all ok, on Windows same problem.

Answer (score 67):

Try `flutter doctor`, you will see `flutter channel unknown`. That is the reason, Flutter uses git to manage the Framework and when you `checkout` to different commit code / tags `flutter channel` changed to `unknown`.

Here is what you have to do:

```
flutter channel stable
```

Above I mentioned `stable`, if you need change the channel that you want to checkout (see available channels by `flutter channel` in terminal / cmd).

Then:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Everything should work now.

If not try below:

Go to flutter framework located directory and set `upstream` by `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/stable stable`.

Please note that `flutter channel stable` is equivalent to `git checkout stable` if you try in flutter framework located directory.

Learn lot more info about this issue from already reported [issue tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14193).

Comment: still not working giving `Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin
https://github.com/flutter/flutter' in C:\flutter`

Comment: @Ali80 So, go to your flutter install directory and open a cmd in that and run `git remote add origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter`

Comment: yeah, still not working saying `remote origin already exists`

Comment: @Ali80 you can replace with the existing one by: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter`

Comment: Please first try `flutter channel` then try `flutter channel stable && git pull && flutter upgrade` (replace stable with desired branch / channel).

Comment: same result, I event deleted the old flutter directory and downloaded `1.17.0 stable`, still flutter upgrade fails with the same message

Comment: did you try `flutter channel`. And if possible show me your `flutter doctor -v` result from a gist or at least screenshot

Comment: I did try flutter channel, I try to switch to stable it says 
`flutter channel stable
Switching to flutter channel 'stable'...
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.12 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.12
git: Already on 'stable'
git: Your branch is up to date with 'origin/stable'.
Successfully switched to flutter channel 'stable'.
To ensure that you're on the latest build from this channel, run 'flutter upgrade'`

Comment: `flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel @u, v1.17.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.29.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.`

Comment: @Ali80 You are on a custom flutter channel named `@u`. May be you have few flutter installations. And the one you are trying to change is not the one setupped to 'Environmenta Variable'. Go to System -> Environmenta Variables and check what is the fluttter path is. If there are multiple delete and locate the correct one.

Comment: the path is correct
running cmd`where flutter
C:\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat`,
I also noticed the channel name`@u` which is odd since I switched to stable and it also says I'm on stable, I as said I got crazy over the error and even deleted the whole directory and downloaded one from `Flutter SDK releases` still with the same results

Comment: @Ali80 Didn't you notice `C:\flutter\bin\flutter` you are in a two flutter directory. Remove last `flutter` which is inside ``C:\flutter\bin` directory and envioromental variable also

Comment: That's not another directory, this flutter directory is directly downloaded and extracted from google's `flutter sdk releases`, I didnt change/add anything inside it, anyway I build an app with this new release `1.17.0` yesterday and today the problem disappeared, I'm on stable channel and flutter upgrade also works! So I guess this is was a weird bug which solved itself by running a build after switching to the new channel

Answer (score 15):

First check the `flutter doctor` response

when you get **channel** **unknown**, follow these steps

In Flutter framework located directory, set upstream by

1. `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/stable stable`.
2. Then,
   `flutter upgrade`

It will fix the error

Comment: After first executing first step, switch to stable branch and then run flutter upgrade

Answer (score 5):

First of all run command in cmd  `flutter channel stable`   then run  `flutter upgrade`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it on Windows, I think this is a git issue:

- ensure `PATH` contains latest Git (mine is `2.25.1`, updated from `1.18`) and `flutter\bin`.
- > `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`
- > `flutter channel master`
- > `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
- > `flutter doctor -v`
- > `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows users -**

Check if you have Git or not. If not download it and put it in the system `PATH`.

Delete the old flutter folder and then run this command in the terminal.

`git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`

After flutter is downloaded completely, run `flutter doctor -v` in the terminal.

Now all your issues will be fixed and all the errors like these will be fixed.

```
"flutter upgrade" command "Unable to upgrade Flutter: no upstream repository configured."

Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured.

Unable to upgrade Flutter: The Flutter SDK is tracking a non-standard remote
```

Answer (score 2):

run command in terminal flutter channel stable then run flutter upgrade.
Still it not works then  run command as below

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter upgrade --force

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install flutter on my new ubuntu pc, following the directions on the official website: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

I went with their initial steps of downloading the flutter sdk directly on my device, rather than cloning a git repo. Due to this my IDE kept popping a notification that the flutter version wasn't compatible.

I just had to delete the installed sdk files, and clone the git repo. This made it work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.I ran flutter channel stable,

I got the below output...

```
E:\flutter_Apps\flutter_app_dont_stare_v2>flutter channel stable
Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is
currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: C:\src\flutter
  previous reference  : C:\flutter\flutter\flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see
which flutter is on your path).

Switching to flutter channel 'stable'...
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:  * [new branch]          Hixie-patch-1          -> origin/Hixie-patch-1
git:  + d3ed9ec94...f994b7697 beta                   -> origin/beta  (forced update)
git:  * [new branch]          dds_integration_take_2 -> origin/dds_integration_take_2
git:    7f56b53de..d9653445f  dev                    -> origin/dev
git:    d3ed9ec94..b041144f8  flutter-1.17-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.17-candidate.3
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.10 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.10
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.11 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.11
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.12 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.12
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.13 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.13
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.6 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.6
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.7 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.7
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.8 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.8
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.18-candidate.9 -> origin/flutter-1.18-candidate.9
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.0 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.0
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.1 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.1
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.2 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.2
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.3
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.4 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.4
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.5 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.5
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.20-candidate.0 -> origin/flutter-1.20-candidate.0
git:    9cc69d47a..401690a64  master                 -> origin/master
git:  * [new branch]          revert-51465-fab-complete-new -> origin/revert-51465-fab-complete-new
git:  * [new branch]          roll_branch            -> origin/roll_branch
git:  + f139b1100...b041144f8 stable                 -> origin/stable  (forced update)
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.3                 -> 1.17.3
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-10.0.pre        -> 1.18.0-10.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-11.0.pre        -> 1.18.0-11.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-11.1.pre        -> 1.18.0-11.1.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-13.0.pre        -> 1.18.0-13.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-7.0.pre         -> 1.18.0-7.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-8.0.pre         -> 1.18.0-8.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-9.0.pre         -> 1.18.0-9.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-0.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-0.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-1.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-1.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-2.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-2.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-3.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-3.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-4.1.pre         -> 1.19.0-4.1.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-5.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-5.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.20.0-0.0.pre         -> 1.20.0-0.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.0                 -> 1.17.0
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.0-3.2.pre         -> 1.17.0-3.2.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.0-3.3.pre         -> 1.17.0-3.3.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.0-3.4.pre         -> 1.17.0-3.4.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.1                 -> 1.17.1
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.2                 -> 1.17.2
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-12.0.pre        -> 1.18.0-12.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.18.0-6.0.pre         -> 1.18.0-6.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-4.0.pre         -> 1.19.0-4.0.pre
git: Your branch and 'origin/stable' have diverged,
git: and have 12 and 1517 different commits each, respectively.
git:   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
git: Previous HEAD position was 0b8abb472 Do not use logcat -T on pre-lollipop Android
git: Switched to branch 'stable'
```

and then  flutter upgrade --force before getting this

```
E:\flutter_Apps\flutter_app_dont_stare_v2>flutter upgrade --force
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408...
Unzipping Dart SDK...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is
currently executing will be used instead.
  running Flutter tool: C:\src\flutter
  previous reference  : C:\flutter\flutter\flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see
which flutter is on your path).

Upgrading Flutter from C:\src\flutter...
Updating files:  23% (891/3793)
Updating files:  24% (911/3793)
Updating files:  25% (949/3793)
Updating files:  26% (987/3793)
Updating files:  27% (1025/3793)
Updating files:  28% (1063/3793)
Updating files:  29% (1100/3793)
Updating files:  30% (1138/3793)
Updating files:  31% (1176/3793)
Updating files:  32% (1214/3793)
Updating files:  33% (1252/3793)
Updating files:  34% (1290/3793)
Updating files:  35% (1328/3793)
Updating files:  36% (1366/3793)
Updating files:  37% (1404/3793)
Updating files:  38% (1442/3793)
Updating files:  39% (1480/3793)
Updating files:  40% (1518/3793)
Updating files:  41% (1556/3793)
Updating files:  41% (1574/3793)
Updating files:  42% (1594/3793)
Updating files:  43% (1631/3793)
Updating files:  44% (1669/3793)
Updating files:  45% (1707/3793)
Updating files:  46% (1745/3793)
Updating files:  47% (1783/3793)
Updating files:  48% (1821/3793)
Updating files:  49% (1859/3793)
Updating files:  50% (1897/3793)
Updating files:  50% (1904/3793)
Updating files:  51% (1935/3793)
Updating files:  52% (1973/3793)
Updating files:  53% (2011/3793)
Updating files:  54% (2049/3793)
Updating files:  55% (2087/3793)
Updating files:  56% (2125/3793)
Updating files:  57% (2163/3793)
Updating files:  58% (2200/3793)
Updating files:  58% (2225/3793)
Updating files:  59% (2238/3793)
Updating files:  60% (2276/3793)
Updating files:  61% (2314/3793)
Updating files:  62% (2352/3793)
Updating files:  62% (2382/3793)
Updating files:  63% (2390/3793)
Updating files:  64% (2428/3793)
Updating files:  65% (2466/3793)
Updating files:  65% (2503/3793)
Updating files:  66% (2504/3793)
Updating files:  67% (2542/3793)
Updating files:  67% (2566/3793)
Updating files:  68% (2580/3793)
Updating files:  69% (2618/3793)
Updating files:  70% (2656/3793)
Updating files:  71% (2694/3793)
Updating files:  72% (2731/3793)
Updating files:  73% (2769/3793)
Updating files:  74% (2807/3793)
Updating files:  74% (2815/3793)
Updating files:  75% (2845/3793)
Updating files:  76% (2883/3793)
Updating files:  77% (2921/3793)
Updating files:  78% (2959/3793)
Updating files:  79% (2997/3793)
Updating files:  79% (3022/3793)
Updating files:  80% (3035/3793)
Updating files:  81% (3073/3793)
Updating files:  82% (3111/3793)
Updating files:  83% (3149/3793)
Updating files:  83% (3161/3793)
Updating files:  84% (3187/3793)
Updating files:  85% (3225/3793)
Updating files:  86% (3262/3793)
Updating files:  87% (3300/3793)
Updating files:  87% (3310/3793)
Updating files:  88% (3338/3793)
Updating files:  89% (3376/3793)
Updating files:  90% (3414/3793)
Updating files:  90% (3439/3793)
Updating files:  91% (3452/3793)
Updating files:  92% (3490/3793)
Updating files:  93% (3528/3793)
Updating files:  93% (3546/3793)
Updating files:  94% (3566/3793)
Updating files:  95% (3604/3793)
Updating files:  96% (3642/3793)
Updating files:  96% (3650/3793)
Updating files:  97% (3680/3793)
Updating files:  97% (3706/3793)
Updating files:  98% (3718/3793)
Updating files:  99% (3756/3793)
Updating files:  99% (3760/3793)
Updating files: 100% (3793/3793)
Updating files: 100% (3793/3793), done.
Updating cf37c2cd0..b041144f8
 dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/assets/999x1000.png |   Bin 0 -> 3561 bytes
 .../benchmarks/macrobenchmarks}/macos/.gitignore   |     0
 .../xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist          |     0
 .../Runner.xcworkspace}/contents.xcworkspacedata   |     0
 .../xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist          |     0
 .../macos/Runner/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib           |     0
 .../macos/Runner/Configs/Debug.xcconfig            |     0
 .../macos/Runner/Configs/Release.xcconfig          |     0
 .../macos/Runner/Configs/Warnings.xcconfig         |     0
 .../macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements         |     0
 .../macrobenchmarks}/macos/Runner/Info.plist       |     0
 .../macos/Runner/Release.entitlements              |     0
 .../android/gradle.properties                      |     0
 .../gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties       |     0
 .../ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist             |     0
 .../ios/Flutter/Flutter.xcconfig                   |     0
 .../xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist          |     0
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@3x.png       |   Bin 0 -> 4867 bytes
 .../ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard  |     0
 .../ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard          |     0
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png   |   Bin
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png   |   Bin
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png  |   Bin
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png |   Bin
 .../src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png    |   Bin
 .../test_apps}/stocks/android/gradle.properties    |     0
 .../gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties       |     0
 .../test_apps}/stocks/fuchsia/meta/stocks.cmx      |     0
 .../stocks/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist      |     0
 .../test_apps/stocks/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig    |     0
 .../project.xcworkspace}/contents.xcworkspacedata  |     0
 .../xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist          |     0
 .../xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme         |     0
 .../Runner.xcworkspace}/contents.xcworkspacedata   |     0
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json               |     0
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-60@2x.png              |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-60@3x.png              |   Bin
 .../Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-76.png |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-76@2x.png              |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-83.5@2x.png            |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Notification.png       |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Notification@2x.png    |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Notification@3x.png    |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small-40.png           |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small-40@2x.png        |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small-40@3x.png        |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small.png              |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small@2x.png           |   Bin
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small@3x.png           |   Bin
 .../ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard  |     0
 .../stocks/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard   |     0
 .../test_apps}/stocks/ios/Runner/Info.plist        |     0
 .../test_apps/stocks/lib/i18n/stocks_en.arb        |     0
 .../test_apps/stocks/lib/i18n/stocks_es.arb        |     0
 dev/devicelab/images/agent-statuses.png            |   Bin 13842 -> 0 bytes
 dev/devicelab/images/broken-test.png               |   Bin 56878 -> 0 bytes
 dev/devicelab/images/legend.png                    |   Bin 30220 -> 0 bytes
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png   |   Bin 0 -> 544 bytes
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png   |   Bin
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png  |   Bin 0 -> 721 bytes
 .../app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png |   Bin 0 -> 1031 bytes
 .../src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png    |   Bin 0 -> 1443 bytes
 .../assets/red_square.png                          |   Bin 0 -> 629 bytes
 .../project.xcworkspace}/contents.xcworkspacedata  |     0
 .../xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme         |     0
 .../Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata    |     0
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png   |   Bin 0 -> 10932 bytes
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png       |   Bin 0 -> 564 bytes
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png       |   Bin 0 -> 1283 bytes
 .../AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png       |   Bin 0 -> 1588 bytes




    and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying 90% of the suggestions on this page and others. Nothing worked for me until I ran "Flutter Channel Stable" in the terminal selected the Menu Tools--> Flutter "Flutter Clean" Waited until the Clean process was completed then File -->"Invalidate Cache and restart"  then Wait until everything is complete. Only after it has completed run Tools-> "Flutter Pub Get" Wait and then run "Flutter Pub Upgrade" Wait until everything is complete and then everything should allow you to code again as normal. This resolved my Git repository issue. If you prefer to go back to the dev channel again that can be done by going to the terminal "Flutter channel dev"

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal and change your directory to C then type :
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable

It will clone and create a folder flutter
then type cd flutter

then run flutter upgrade --force command

It will take a few minutes ...

then restart vs code

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you are using for non-supported OS (Aurora OS in my case) is to do

```
cd {your flutter directory get with e.g. flutter-aurora doctor -v}
git checkout master
git fetch
git config pull.rebase true
git pull
flutter-aurora doctor
```