# Unable to upgrade flutter no origin repository configured

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm running "flutter upgrade" and I get the message: Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add
origin https://github.com/flutter/flutter' in
/flutter

I've tried running that command, it says the origin is already configured. I've tried everything here: [Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59962491/unable-to-upgrade-flutter-no-origin-repository-configured]) but I get the same error message.

I've also tried:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Same no origin repoistory error.

However if I run "git pull" the upgrade process runs successfully. I'm not sure why the flutter upgrade command won't work though.

flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: try Following Coomand  "flutter upgrade --force"

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya still says no origin configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleteing the flutter folder: User/Development/flutter then running
 `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable` to re-downlod flutter solved the issue.