# Flutter - I can't see any channel

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am trying to upgrade my flutter. When I hit flutter upgrade in the terminal in the android studio I receive the error 'Unable to upgrade Flutter: no origin repository configured. Run 'git remote add origin [https://github.com/flutter/flutter''](https://github.com/flutter/flutter%27%27).

When I try to see flutter channels, I type flutter channel in the terminal in android studio, but I can't see any channels. The list is empty.   [Check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QIeS.png)

After running the flutter channel stable in the terminal, it switched successfully. I ran the flutter upgrade command again and the same issue happened again. The screenshot is attached. [New screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZQch.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `flutter doctor`, you will see `flutter channel unknown`. That is the reason, Flutter uses git to manage the Framework and when you `checkout` to different commit code / tags `flutter channel` changed to `unknown`.

Here is what you have to do:

```
flutter channel stable
```

Above I mentioned `stable`, if you need change the channel that you want to checkout (see available channels by `flutter channel` in terminal / cmd).

Then:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Everything should work now.

If not try below:

Go to flutter framework located directory and set `upstream` by `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/stable stable`.

Please note that `flutter channel stable` is equivalent to `git checkout stable` if you try in flutter framework located directory.

Learn lot more info about this issue from already reported [issue tracker](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14193).

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59962492/13412985).

Comment: I have done what you said but I am facing the same issue again. I have attached a new screenshot with my question. Please have a look at that. Thank you!

Comment: Check out this  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14193, a detailed discussion, and a number of solutions are there on this GitHub issue. One of these might surely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. This (git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/stable stable) worked for me.

Comment: Why is this still an issue? I have the same problem with a fresh install of flutter and changing+upgrading to any channel doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try to run `flutter stable channel` and then `flutter upgrade`.

That should work.

Comment: I have done what you said but I am facing the same issue again. I have attached a new screenshot with my question. Please have a look at that. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, i have been searching for the solution for more than 4 hours. So finally i found a simple command for mac users, might it also works on window.

open android Studio and terminal:

flutter channel stable && git pull && flutter upgrade

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).